# как проверить существование значения в таком массиве объектов Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
return вот так выводит, gettype пишет что это object
[
  {"id":1,"name":"Test1"},
  {"id":2,"name":"Test2"},
]

Есть какая то функция уже готовая чтобы без костылей проверить есть ли значение в этом объекте "Test2"
```

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это [коллекция](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#available-methods), то можно например

```php
$collection = collect([
    ['product' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
    ['product' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],
]);
 
$collection->contains('product', 'Bookcase');

// false
```